# Threads don't start when compiling with optimization flag

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++17

I have written a simple Worker Pool program. When I compile it without -Ox flag it runs as expected, but when i use -Ox (x>0) or -Og threads do not start.

`worker_pool.h`

```cpp
#ifndef WORKER_POOL_H
#define WORKER_POOL_H

#include <sema.h>

#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class worker_pool {
private:
  class worker {
  private:
    worker_pool *wp;
    long id;

  public:
    worker(worker_pool *_wp, long _id) : wp(_wp), id(_id){};

    void operator()() {
      while (!wp->stop) {
        printf("monkey %d doing job\n", int(id));
        auto t = wp->fetch();
        if (!t.has_value())
          continue;
        else
          t.value()();
      }
    };
  };

  std::vector<std::thread> workers;
  std::queue<std::function<void(void)>> q;
  std::mutex mx;
  Semaphore sm;
  std::condition_variable cv_empty;
  std::mutex mx_empty;

  std::optional<std::function<void(void)>> fetch() {
    sm.wait();
    std::unique_lock l(mx);
    if (stop)
      return {};
    auto res = std::move(q.front());
    q.pop();
    if (q.empty())
      cv_empty.notify_all();
    return std::move(res);
  };

public:
  worker_pool(long tcount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) {
    for (long i = 0; i < tcount; i++) {
      workers.push_back(std::move(std::thread(worker(this, i))));
    }
  }

  ~worker_pool() { terminate(); }

  worker_pool(worker_pool const &) = delete;
  worker_pool &operator=(worker_pool const &) = delete;
  worker_pool(worker_pool &&) = delete;
  worker_pool &operator=(worker_pool &&) = delete;

  bool stop;

  template <typename F, typename... ARGS>
  auto submit(F &&f, ARGS &&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {
    std::lock_guard l(mx);
    auto func = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward(args)...);
    auto task_ptr =
        std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()>>(func);
    q.push([task_ptr] { (*task_ptr)(); });
    sm.signal();
    return task_ptr->get_future();
  }

  void terminate() {
    stop = true;
    sm.signal(workers.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < workers.capacity(); i++) {
      if (workers[i].joinable())
        workers[i].join();
    }
  }

  long jobs_remaining() {
    std::lock_guard l(mx);
    return q.size();
  }

  void wait_until_empty() {
    std::unique_lock l(mx_empty);
    while (!(q.empty() || stop))
      cv_empty.wait(l, [&] { return q.empty() || stop; });
  }
};

#endif // WORKER_POOL_H
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <sema.h>
#include <worker_pool.h>

#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  printf("creating worker pool\n");
  worker_pool wp(4);
  vector<future<string>> futures;
  printf("creating jobs\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    futures.push_back(
        wp.submit([]() { return std::move(string("Hello world")); }));
  }
  printf("waiting for jobs to finish\n");
  wp.wait_until_empty();
  for (auto &f : futures) {
    auto str = f.get();
    cout << str << endl;
  }
  printf("finished jobs\n");
  wp.terminate();

  cout << "program ended" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation commands:
`clang++ -std=c++17 -pthread -g   -Iinclude  -Llib src/main.cpp -o bin/gmain`
`clang++ -std=c++17 -pthread -Iinclude -Llib -O3 src/main.cpp -o bin/main`
Clang version 8, GCC version 8.2.1.

Comment: This is already pretty small, but formally it is probably not a [mcve], because that would be just a single file. Also, you write "threads do not start", but that's an interpretation, while the actual observations would be necessary. So, what did you see and what did you expect to see? That said, compiling without warnings is a bad idea, that's another thing I'd fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour, flag `bool stop;` is never initialized, so in thread body

```
while (!wp->stop) {
```

everything may happen , i.e. you return immediately from thread.

Add

```
bool stop = false;
```